# Linq to Entity append common where with different tables

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, extension-methods, where-clause

Right now I have a bunch of data access methods using SqlConnections/StringBuilder/SqlDataReader. I am trying to move some of these over to entity framework. I have a method that dynamically appends a where clause like:

```
sb.AppendLine(" WHERE ");
sb.AppendLine(" (@Value1 is null or Table1.Id = @Value1) " );
sb.AppendLine(" AND (@Value2 is null or Table2.Field = @Value2)" );
sb.AppendLine(" AND (@Value3 is null or Table3.Stuff = @Value3)" );
```

Is it possible to replicate this behavior in L2E Method syntax? I need it to be available for a bunch of different methods. Could this be made into an extension method? How would it work with different queries selecting from different tables?

Comment: is it `AND` or `OR` that seperates the conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could look something like this:

```
var qry = db.SomeTable
            .Where(c => value1 == null || c.Table1.Id == value1)
            .Where(c => value2 == null || c.Table2.Field == value2)
            .Where(c => value3 == null || c.Table3.Stuff == value3);
```

**UPDATE**
How to make it accessible to diffenrent queries?
*If* by other query - you mean other instances of `IQueryable<SomeTable>` then you could use an [exention method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) :

```
public static class MyExtentions
{
   public static IQueryable<SomeTable> ApplyCondition(this IQueryable<SomeTable> source)
   {
      return source
               .Where(c => value1 == null || c.Table1.Id == value1)
               .Where(c => value2 == null || c.Table2.Field == value2)
               .Where(c => value3 == null || c.Table3.Stuff == value3);
   }
}
```

then you could call it like this:

```
var qry = db.SomeTable.ApplyCondition();
```

Comment: @Shawn bnote sure if this is what you mean/need, but see my edit

Comment: I should've been more specific. By different queries I mean queries on different tables.

Answer (score 0):

something like this, you could join tb1 in Table1 on tb1.Id =  equals (@Value1==null? @Value1: tb1.Id).